# ¿Cómo buscar en una lista de objetos (diccionarios) un elemento con python?

Tags: python, json, lista, diccionarios

Actualmente me encuentro con la necesidad de buscar un diccionario dentro de una lista utilizando una llave, que es única.

Ejemplo:

```
list_ejem =[{'id':1,'name':'juan','age':19},{'id':2,'name':'jose','age':24},{'id':3,'name':'maria','age':22},{'id':4,'name':'ana','age':18}]
```

Quiero poder traer el diccionario que tenga el id 4 por ejemplo,
Y posteriormente tal vez quiero sacar el diccionario que tenga el nombre "Juan".

Lo intente hacer con un ciclo for pero siento que es demasiado robusto, me gustaría saber si existe una forma más **óptima**, ya que realizó esta clase de tareas con muchas listas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una lista no es un diccionario, el acceso rápido a un elemento individual es por medio de un indice numérico. En tu caso, dónde necesitas encontrar un diccionario que tenga cierta valor en la clave `id` lamentablemente no puedes escapar de una búsqueda secuencial. Eventualmente puedes usar comprensión de listas para hacer más compacto el código:

```
print(list(e for e in list_ejem if e['id']  == 4)[0])
print(list(e for e in list_ejem if e['name']  == 'Juan')[0])
```

Comment: Excelente respuesta, ahora me gustaría saber si recomiendas el uso de lista comprimida o una función de orden superior como es la función filter , la manera en que lo resolvi es:  `list(filter(lambda x: x["id"]==4, list_ejem))[0]`  que es muy parecido a lo que propones, ¿cual es mas óptimo?

Comment: Ambas formas son equivalentes, en cuanto a lo que hacen, no creo que haya diferencias en cuanto a performance. Te recomendaría que uses la que te resulte más clara. En caso que solo te interesar un único posible elemento, podrías eventualmente ganar algo de tiempo usando lo que te propone FJSevilla, un ciclo con un break ni bien se encuentre el elemento.

Answer (score 1):

Si con única te refieres a que solo existe dentro de la lista un diccionario con ese valor, la forma más eficiente es un ciclo `for` normal con un cortocircuito:

```
from typing import Any, Hashable, Iterable, Optional


def buscar_dicc(it: Iterable[dict], clave: Hashable, valor: Any) -> Optional[dict]:
    for dicc in it:
        if dicc[clave] == valor:
            return dicc
    return None
```

> ```
> >>> list_ejem =[{'id':1,'name':'juan','age':19},
>                 {'id':2,'name':'jose','age':24},
>                 {'id':3,'name':'maria','age':22},
>                 {'id':4,'name':'ana','age':18}]
>
> >>> buscar_dicc(list_ejem, "id", 3)
> {'id': 3, 'name': 'maria', 'age': 22}
>
> >>> buscar_dicc(list_ejem, "name", "maria")
> {'id': 3, 'name': 'maria', 'age': 22}
>  
> >>> buscar_dicc(list_ejem, "name", "pepe")
> None
> ```

Si queremos que retorne también `None` si se busca una clave que no está en alguno de los diccionarios o en en ninguno en vez de generar una excepción `KeyError`, podemos recurrir a `dict.get` (que supone una pequeña sobrecarga):

```
from typing import Any, Hashable, Iterable, Optional


def buscar_dicc(it: Iterable[dict], clave: Hashable, valor: Any) -> Optional[dict]:
    for dicc in it:
        if dicc.get(clave) == valor:
            return dicc
    return None
```

> ```
> >>> buscar_dicc(list_ejem, "foo", "bar")
> None
> ```

La clave está en que si sabemos que solo hay un diccionario con esa pareja clave: valor, no romper el ciclo si lo encontramos es un consumo de recursos inútil. Imagina que el diccionario está el primero en la lista, si tenemos una lista de  1.000.000 de diccionarios iteramos 1.000.000 cuando basta 1...

Las listas por compresión no son siempre la panacea, su principal virtud en cuanto a eficiencia es evitar la llamada a `list.append`. Hay muchas veces en las que un simple `for` es mejor opción, no solo por legibilidad, también por eficiencia.

Otra opción es la tirar de programación funcional con`filter`, pero aunque está optimizado a nivel de C, llamamos a una función por cada item, lo que de nuevo es una sobrecarga importante solo para realizar una comparación de igualdad.

---

Si cabe la posibilidad de que el valor se repita y quieras todos los diccionarios,si la eficiencia te importa, entonces si, usa una lista por compresión, expresión generadora o función generadora directamente, por ejemplo, retornando una lista:

```
from typing import Any, Hashable, Iterable, List    


def buscar_diccs(it: Iterable[dicc], clave: Hashable, valor: Any) -> List[dict]:
    return [dicc for dicc in it if dicc[clave] == valor] # O dicc.get
```

He metido el código en funciones para facilitar la reutilización simplemente. Si no se usa una función, debemos usar break para romper los ciclos:

```
clave = "id"
valor = 4

for dicc in it:
    if dicc[clave] == valor:
        break
else:
    dicc = None

print(dicc)
```

Answer (score 0):

If input("necesitas solamente una lista de diccionarios que puedas acceder desde su ID o no??").lower() not in ("s","si","y","yes"): print("""creo que te sirve este formato por ejemplo:

> ejemplo={"1":{"nombre":"juan"},"2":{"nombre":"camila"}}
> ejemplo["1"]
> {"nombre":"juan"}
> ejemplo["2"]
> {"nombre":"camila"}

Con esto se podría evitar la iteración de 1000 elementos (en tal caso) y con ello se evita la sobre carga
""")
else: print("ok, no creo que te sirva mi idea")